# Installation failed with postinstall script Mac OSX

Tags: python, macos, pkgbuild, productbuild

I am trying to create package using pkgbuild and product archive using productbuild. 
Without scripts, the Installer installs the package successfully. But with scripts, it fails. I googled for it, but couldnt' find a working solution that fixes my issues.

pkgbuild --root GameDir --install-location /Applications --component-plist 'info.plist' --scripts ScriptsOSX Game.pkg

The .app name is provided in the info.plist as RootRelativeBundlePath Dictionary value

productbuild --distribution ./Distribution.xml --resources ../Resources --packagepath GamePkgDir GameInstaller.pkg

script in GameDir/ScriptsOSX folder :
postinsall.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
open /Applications/Contacts.app/
exit 0
```

Permission : 
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1   staff  57 Dec 12 19:26 postinstall.sh
// Execution permission for all, for testing purposes.

fwiw : When Installation proceeds, it asks for admin password to proceed. Hence I believe it has permission to run the script, in addition to the execution permission.

I attempted first using python script. Though installation succeeded, the script did not execute. I am not sure why. All the examples had shell or perl script as installation script, hence attempting shell script. But installation fails. I am sure it is due to attempt at script execution. But not sure why. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Sujatha

EDIT : 
The info.plist that has post install script goes like this
Its is an array of dictionaries, in which one of the key:value pair is  : BundlePostInstallScriptPath = postinstall.sh

Comment: When you say it fails, what messages do you get?

Comment: The error is "The installer encountered an error that caused the installation to fail. Contact the software manufacturer for assistance" . Not very useful one. And the software manufacturer is me. :)

Comment: Found the error and fixed it. Informing here so it might help any other person stumbling across this post for similar issue. The issue was indeed with the script. The scripts path in the option "--scripts xxx" was using wrong script. An old one that had BundlePostInstallScriptPath = postinstall.py. I was packaging two pkgs into a single flat package. and was testing with the wrong .py script instead of the .sh script. .sh script works now, and opens the application successfully.

Answer (score 3):

One can always look into `/var/log/install.log` for more informations.